# How to install openmpi modules in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: compiling, 18.04, gnu, fortran

Several modules of `openmpi` are missing in the repository of Ubuntu 18.04. I need to compile a program with `fortra`n and ended up with the errors:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lblacs-openmpi
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lblacsCinit-openmpi
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lblacsF77init-openmpi
```

I had no problem in Ubuntu 16.04. How can I install the missing modules?

Comment: @steeldriver exactly. It solved my problem!

Comment: @steeldriver please write an answer that Mr. or Ms. Google Robot can accept.

Comment: @Googlebot please accept Steel's answer below. This will help other users know it solves your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing libraries are provided by the [libblacs-mpi-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libblacs-mpi-dev/filelist) package. The solution is to install the package, either via a GUI software manager or via the command line

```
sudo apt install libblacs-mpi-dev
```